# Changing a part of an image

Tags: image, matlab

How can I paste back a part of my picture after I changed it in MATLAB? I cropped the plates off this image of a car and now I want to put it back automatically. The plates are still at the same coordinates as they were initially, but the background is all black.

The car I want to paste on:

[image: Car]

And this is what I want to paste:

[image: to paste]

Here is my code, I want to change the part where I need to draw by hand the plate.

```
fontSize = 20;
format compact;

baseFileName1 = 'blurr_plate.jpg';
baseFileName2 = 'car2.jpg';

sourceImage = imread(baseFileName1);
subplot(1, 2, 1);
imshow(sourceImage);
axis on;
caption = sprintf('Source image, %s', baseFileName1);
title(caption, 'FontSize', fontSize, 'Interpreter', 'none');

% Enlarge figure to full screen.
set(gcf, 'units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]);
% Give a name to the title bar.
set(gcf,'name','Demo by ImageAnalyst','numbertitle','off')

targetImage = imread(baseFileName2);
subplot(1, 2, 2);
imshow(targetImage);
axis on; 
caption = sprintf('Target image, %s, original', baseFileName2);
title(caption, 'FontSize', fontSize, 'Interpreter', 'none');

% Ask user to draw freehand mask.
message = sprintf('In the LEFT IMAGE...\nLeft click and hold to begin drawing.\nSimply lift the mouse button to finish');
subplot(1, 2, 1);
uiwait(msgbox(message));
hFH = imfreehand(); % Actual line of code to do the drawing.
% Create a binary image ("mask") from the ROI object.
mask = hFH.createMask();
xy = hFH.getPosition;

% Paste it onto the target image.
targetImage(mask) = sourceImage(mask);

% Display new image.
subplot(1, 2, 2); % Switch active axes to right hand axes.
imshow(targetImage);
imwrite(targetImage, 'car_new.jpg')
axis on;
caption = sprintf('Target image, %s, after paste', baseFileName2);
title(caption, 'FontSize', fontSize, 'Interpreter', 'none');
```

Comment: Can you show us some code ;-)

Comment: I used this code, but it works only if I draw the part I want cropped, and both images are grayscale https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/48912/copy_paste_image_freehand.m

Comment: Thanks for the link to the code. It is quite long, though. In order to make it more easy for somebody to help, could you please reduce it to a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem you have with it?

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work only in case when both source and target images are grayscale. As your target image is coloured, make following changes:

Delete line number 35,36 and 41.

paste this code after line 33.

```
    redChannel = targetImage(:, :, 1);
    greenChannel = targetImage(:, :, 2);
    blueChannel = targetImage(:, :, 3);
    redChannel(mask) = sourceImage(mask);
    greenChannel(mask) = sourceImage(mask);
    blueChannel(mask) = sourceImage(mask);
    targetImage = cat(3, redChannel, greenChannel, blueChannel);
```